# How to parse xml using xmllint and store in arrays

Tags: bash, shell, xml-parsing, xmllint

In shell script, I have an xml file as p.xml, as follows and I want to parse it and get values in two arrays. I am trying to use xmllint, but could not get desired data.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Share_Collection>
      <Share id="data/Backup" resource-id="data/Backup" resource-type="SimpleShare" share-name="Backup" protocols="cifs,afp"/>
      <Share id="data/Documents" resource-id="data/Documents" resource-type="SimpleShare" share-name="Documents" protocols="cifs,afp"/>
      <Share id="data/Music" resource-id="data/Music" resource-type="SimpleShare" share-name="Music" protocols="cifs,afp"/>
      <Share id="data/OwnCloud" resource-id="data/OwnCloud" resource-type="SimpleShare" share-name="OwnCloud" protocols="cifs,afp"/>
      <Share id="data/Pictures" resource-id="data/Pictures" resource-type="SimpleShare" share-name="Pictures" protocols="cifs,afp"/>
      <Share id="data/Videos" resource-id="data/Videos" resource-type="SimpleShare" share-name="Videos" protocols="cifs,afp"/>
    </Share_Collection>
```

I want to get an array all share ids and one array containing share-names. So two array would be like

```
share-ids-array = ["data/Backup", "data/Documents", "data/Music", "data/OwnCloud", "data/Pictures", "data/Videos"]     

share-names-array = ["Backup", "Documents", "Music", "OwnCloud", "Pictures", "Videos"]
```

I started as follows:

```
xmllint --xpath '//Share/@id' p.xml 
xmllint --xpath '//Share/@share-name' p.xml
```

that gives me

```
id="data/Backup" 
id="data/Documents" id="data/Music" id="data/OwnCloud" id="data/Pictures" id="data/Videos"
```

Any help to build those two arrays will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one solution with grep (and tr)...sed or awk are other alternatives. By the way, you cannot use hyphens in variable names in bash.

```
share_ids=($( xmllint --xpath '//Share/@id' p.xml | grep -Po '".*?"' | tr -d \" ))
share_names=($( xmllint --xpath '//Share/@share-name' p.xml | grep -Po '".*?"' | tr -d \" ))
```

Example:

```
$ echo ${share_names[@]}
Backup Documents Music OwnCloud Pictures Videos
```

Using *xmlstarlet* is probably better, though:

```
share_names=($( xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//Share/@share-name' -v '.' -n p.xml ))
```